# Как заменить текст между точками?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Делаю вывод даты с текстовым месяцем. От даты отнимается несколько дней.

Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы заменить текст между точками, и точки на пробелы?

Например, сегодня 08.05.2019. Отнимаем 15 дней, и выводим "23 апреля 2019".

```
$_monthsList = array(".01." => "января", ".02." => "февраля", 
".03." => "марта", ".04." => "апреля", ".05." => "мая", ".06." => "июня", 
".07." => "июля", ".08." => "августа", ".09." => "сентября",
".10." => "октября", ".11." => "ноября", ".12." => "декабря");

$currentDate = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
date_modify($currentDate, '-15 day');
$date =  date_format($currentDate, 'd.m.Y');

$date = preg_replace(регулярное выражение, " ".$_monthsList[$_mD]." ", $date);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) и регулярное выражение `'~\.\d{2}\.~'`:

```
$_monthsList = array(".01." => "января", ".02." => "февраля", 
".03." => "марта", ".04." => "апреля", ".05." => "мая", ".06." => "июня", 
".07." => "июля", ".08." => "августа", ".09." => "сентября",
".10." => "октября", ".11." => "ноября", ".12." => "декабря");

$currentDate = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
date_modify($currentDate, '-15 day');
$date = date_format($currentDate, 'd.m.Y');

$date = preg_replace_callback('~\.\d{2}\.~', function ($m) use ($_monthsList) {
    return isset($_monthsList[$m[0]]) ?  " " . $_monthsList[$m[0]] . " " : $m[0];
 }, $date);
echo $date; // - 23 апреля 2019
```

См. [демо на PHP онлайн](https://3v4l.org/LkpSl).

Выражение `\.\d{2}\.` находит точку, затем 2 цифры и снова точку.